# `WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction` can not apply springSecuirty configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I tried to write a `@SpringBootTest` to verify the RESTful APIs with users, but when I used  `WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction` to initialize a `WebTestClient` instance, it can not apply the `springSecurity` configuration.

```java
@SpringBootTest()
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction;

    WebTestClient client;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.client = WebTestClient
                .bindToRouterFunction(this.routerFunction)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .configureClient()
                .build();
    }
```

But when using the `ApplicationContext` to build a `WebTestClient` instance, it worked well.

The [complete test codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-redis/src/test/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplicationTests.java) can be found on Github.

Comment: `it can not apply the springSecurity configuration` ofc it cant, since the test will only instantiate the RouterFunction and not the entire context, including all beans for instance the beans that create the security. So that works as intended

Comment: @Toerktumlare as I know, only the test slice, eg. `@WebMvcTest` loads partial context for test, `@SpringBootTest` will load all beans in the test

Comment: read the docs `Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).` not `@Configuration` also in the docs `If you are looking to load your full application configuration and use MockMVC, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined with @AutoConfigureMockMvc rather than this annotation. `

Comment: so, no, no configuration is loaded